# Writing a Code to Indent Code

Tags: c, indentation

My goal is to write a C program that indents the C code given in `char *input`. The style of one level of indentation is given in the string `const char *pad`. I've wrote the following code, which works find in my head but doesn't in practice. There must be a mistake somewhere, but I can't find it. 
Also, I can't figure out why Valgrind doesn't like the line containing while(...). Invalid read of size 1...

Any `{` increases the indentation level by one, and any `}` decreases the indentation level by one. No other indentation rules are applied. I assume there are no curly brackets inside string literals.

```
char *indent(char *input, const char *pad)
{
    int lenpad = strlen(pad);
    int inlen = strlen(input);
    char *output = malloc(inlen+lenpad*90); //Here I'm praying +lenpad*90 is enough
    int indent = 0; 
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int ndx;
    int ondx;
    char current = 'a';
    int n;

    for(ndx=ondx=0; ndx<inlen; ndx++){
        current = input[ndx];
        if(current == '{') indent++;
        if(current == '\n'){
            output[ondx++] = '\n';
            n = ondx;
            while(input[n] != '\n' && input[n] != '\0'){ //Trying to check if the line to come has a curly bracket.
                if(input[n] == '}') //If it does, don't indent that line anymore.
                    indent--;
                n++;
            }
            for(j=0; j<indent; j++){
               for(i=0; i<lenpad; i++){
                output[ondx++] = pad[i];
                } 
            }
        }
        else{
            output[ondx++] = current;
        }
    }
    free(input);
    output[ondx] = '\0';
    return output;
}
```

Instead of:

```
int main(void) {
    printf("asdfasdf\n");
    while (1)
    {
        while (2) {
            printf("printsomething\n");
        }
    }
}
```

My code gives:

```
int main(void) {
        printf("asdfasdf\n");
        while (1)
        {
            while (2) {
                printf("printsomething\n");
            }
            }
            }
```

Comment: is there a reason you want to write this instead one of the code beautifiers out there?

Comment: Did you try to debug this yourself? If not reading this might inspire you: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Why five upvotes? No, not just because its nicely indented ...

Comment: "*I'm praying +lenpad*90 is enough*" No, I refuse to enter this plane.

Comment: To not be misunderstood, I feel this is a nice execise! :-)  But exactly because of this you should solve it youself. 100%. Really.

Comment: By setting a break point in the line `indent--;` (inside the conditional), we can see that *this* line is never executed.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I finally noticed I wrote n = ondx instead of using ndx. I can't believe I didn't find that after looking at it for over 3 hours. I'll try fixing the rest later or tomorrow, since it still throws errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a code beautifier as the one you are trying to write, you **must** :

- swallow (do not output) all initial white spaces in a line (following a `\n`)
- replace them by the proper indentation computed as you do from the number of `{` and `}`

Implement it and ask here if you cannot make it work

Comment: I've got the code working now. Now I only have to implement what you suggested. I'll try to implement it.

Comment: With ace's and your help I was able to get it to work correctly! Thank you for pushing me in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 2):

Change your line

```
n = ondx;
```

to

```
n = ndx + 1;
```

You want `n` be the index of the next item in the input, not the output.